# How to create a file system directory in a SQL Server 2005 call/query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to create a directory for sql server backups. I have to dynamically place the backup file in different folders on many different sql server installs. The backup fails if the directory doesn't exist. So if I can create the directory in a stored procedure or some other call before I call the backup command that would be helpful. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
declare @Path varchar(100)
set @Path = 'c:\CreatedFromSQL'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @Path
```

Sourced from http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1460

Comment: You mark it as the selected answer by clicking the "Tick" below the Vote counter in my answer.

Comment: I tried this very same code, and can't find a "CreatedFromSql" folder anywhere in C:\. What should I do?